# Convergence in distribution implies stochastic boundedness

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, asymptotics, weak-convergence

If $X_n$ converges in distribution to a random variable $X$ , then show that $X_n = O_p(1)$. Can anyone provide me with an approach how to solve this?

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850112/weak-convergence-implies-stochastic-boundedness