# Are all continuous random variables bounded in probablity?

Tags: probability, statistics

In Woodridge's book on econometrics, he mentions that

> If $x_N$ converges to $x$ in distribution, where $x$ is any continuous random variable, then $x_N$ is bounded in probability.

He left it as an exercise. In particular, I think this implies that any continuous random variable is bounded in probability. But I cannot even prove this corollary. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your definition of bounded in probability? Also, a proof for the exercise can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850112/weak-convergence-implies-stochastic-boundedness) or in Asymptotic Statistics by A.W. van der Vaart (Theorem 2.4, page 8).